# Add a class to a div depending on which term was clicked

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Since clicking on a taxonomy term opens a page showing all pages using that term, how do I **identify which term was clicked** so I can add a unique icon to each one? What do I type in *template.php* so I can add it to my *page.tpl.php* like so: `class="<?php if(this-term-was-clicked) : ?> add-this-class <?php endif; ?>"`

I have 3 terms right now and would like to customize the display of each one by adding a unique icon before the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The taxonomy term that is click will already have the class "active" applied to it.

The selector `.field-type-taxonomy-term-reference a.active` is the one you are probably looking for.